# Issues with graph plotting

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a 2 variable function but whenever I try to put it all in the same plot it shows different.
Any sugestions on what could be making this happen??

The function is defined like this Jt[x_,d_]= (1/((d^2) + (x^2))) + (1/((d^2) + (10 - x)^2))

[image: This are all the individual plots i want to be in a same graph]

[image: This is the outcome when i plot it all togheter]

Comment: Other than the plots being on different scales, what is different?

Comment: Do you need to use the option `PlotRange`?